# What is known about finite-dimensional non-semisimple associative algebras over $\Bbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules

Artin-Wedderburn says the semisimple ones are sums of matrix algebras, but what about the non-semisimple ones? What are some examples?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted for closure. This is a perfectly reasonable question for this site...

Comment: For example, $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/I$ where $\sqrt{I}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $I\neq \sqrt{I}$ would be such (commutative) ones. So, the question is much too general to have a good answer without further hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Well, look at what you're asking: "we understand finite dimensional algebras with Jacobson radical zero. What about the rest?" That is a huge class of rings, of course, not substantially different from asking "What can we say about finite dimensional $\Bbb C$ algebras?"

Of course you can say they all have matrix representations in some ring $\Bbb M_n(\Bbb C)$, or that they're Artinian, but this is not very specific.

For examples you can pick any nonzero finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ and look at the ring

$$
R:=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&v\\0&b\end{bmatrix}\mid a,b\in \Bbb C, v\in V\right\}
$$

which has Jacobson radical $\begin{bmatrix}0&V\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and dimension $\dim(V)+2$.

If you look at the subring with $a=b$, then you get a commutative local ring, even.